# How to provide ui-select with a constant choice?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have a searchable dropdown with many values. I am using `ui-select` to filter values on user input. I dont want to show more than 30 values at a time. However I want to inform the user that there are more data available if the user continues to write/filter. How would you solve that?

My idea was to somehow add an extra disabled element to the list, which reads something like `'More results...'`, if there are more than 30 items. Is there any way to provide `ui-select` with a constant choice which it does not filter?
If one scrolls the dropdown it would then be clear that there are more data but that is not being displayed.

```
        <ui-select ng-model="vm.selectedOption" close-on-select="true" on-select="vm.optionSelected($item)" spinner-enabled="true">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="{{'Select option'}}">
                <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
            </ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices
                repeat="option in vm.options"
                refresh="vm.loadOptions($select.search)"
                refresh-delay="200"
                ui-disable-choice="option.isConstantChoice=== true"
            >
                <div ng-bind-html="option.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add an extra element in the array you are using for the generation or even better solution is to separate real data from UI and append that element with something like:

```
var html='<div ng-if="' + expressionForShowingelement + '">Value</div>',
    el = document.getElementById('targetelementId');

angular.element(el).append( $compile(html)($scope) )
```

And then original source stays the same and UI is separated from data/logic. 
Be careful not to mix the single and double quotes marks and break the HTML.

Don't forget to set that `id` you are targeting with `append()` later and disable the element for selection.

Also, keep in mind if you are responding to an outside of AngularJS event, you need to call in `$apply`.

Comment: I get your idea but how would you append it to the `ui-select-choices` element? When I do, it is still being filtered.